# Angular load a lot of image

Tags: angular

I have about 1k images in my project and I would like to avoid backend. I want to have a json that contains all my images (the path) and object description (id, name ecc..) and all my images inside the assets directory.

Is this stupid? There is a way to not load all the images and load in a lazy way? Thank u!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, i have never seen 1k images stored in front.. but i guess it depends on what kind of images they are. But you definitely cannot render 1k big images in one go, that will caouse performance problem, browser will freeze for few secs which is not exactly good user experience. check angular virtual scrolling docs `https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview`

Comment: Thank u for reply. I will show 50 images for time, the point is that I will storage the images in the asset directory.